# many Confirmation Emails being rejected by customers' receiving mail service (confused for spam) How to setup a 3rd party mailing solution?

Tags: email, magento-1, order-email

We are having a serious problem - many (like 3 or 4 every day) customers never receive their Order Confirmation Email due to the fact that their mail service (whatever that may be) confuses our Order Confirmation Email for spam (which it's not obviously).

What are the possible solutions to this? Someone suggested a 3rd party mailing service - does Google offer this and is that a good service to get? How do you set that up technically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start off by installing Aschroder's SMTPpro module: https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension

It easily connects to remote SMTP servers and has several presents for Gmail, Sendgrid etc.

If you have Google Apps for your domain, which is around $4 per account per month you can use Googles SMTP server. This is probably the cheapest solution. Otherwise you might want to look at a service like Sendgrid or Mandrill which are basically the same.

The most important thing is to know how many emails you send since there are small differences in the bundle prices.

But in the end there are a lot of SMTP / Email send service providers. It comes down to the budget you have and amount of emails you send.